# Runge Kutta Method

Tags: numerical-methods

Here,$$y'(x)=x^2+y^2,y(0.9)=14.3$$ I calculated the value of $y(1.0)$ using step sizes of h=0.1 and then h=0.05. However,my result for the different step sizes are very different. I got $y(1.0)=857.0534553$ for h=1.0 and $y(1.0)=187611.525$ for h=0.05 These values are very different from each other. Now, what conclusion can I derive from these two results.

Comment: May be, the function $y(x)$ is not continuous close to $x=1$

Comment: I want to comment on the results, Is the value of y(1.0) is more accurate for h=0.1 or 0.05

Comment: At $x=0.9$, $y=14.3$ and $y'=205.3$ and I think that none of the numbers approximates the real value of the function at $x=1$. I have the feeling that your two values reveal a discontinuity somewhere close to $x=1$ (probably between $0.9$ and $1.0$).

Comment: I used the formula for Runge Kutta of fourth order.

Comment: Why not try it again with $h \approx 0.0001$ or smaller?

Comment: ok then, but can you tell me what can I expect to the results if I use h=0.0001 or h=0.001, which one gives me more accurate value.

Comment: Typically smaller step size leads to higher accuracy, although this isn't universally true.  Some stability regions are not convex and you may pass into and out of the region.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that $y'(x) = x^2 + y^2 > y^2$ for $x > 0$, so your solution grows faster than $$y(x) = {1\over 0.9699-x},$$ a solution of $y' = y^2$ with $y(0.9) \approx 14.3$.  What can you learn from this comparison?